# How can I save opened tabs and tab groups in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, layout, tabs, save, restore

I need to have different set of open tabs and tab groups for each of my tasks.

Import and export setting not helping me to do this, neither does [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736754/can-i-save-the-window-layout-in-visual-studio-2010-2012) that has been asked similarly but for windows/tools layout - i.e. NOT for the tabs/tab-groups.

How can I save and restore the saved set?

Answer (score 21):

Late to the party here but it popped up pretty high in my google search for this kind of thing so I'll drop my find: [Save All The Tabs](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c5642e8-f6aa-4353-830c-946a315c163d?SRC=VSIDE).

Comment: This is no longer compatible. Breaks on install.

Comment: This apparently evolved another plugin (same author): [Restore Editors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.restore-editors)

Comment: @JoãoPCBertoldo That is for **VS Code,** _not_ Visual Studio

Comment: Currently not supported on VS 2019+

Answer (score 18):

One Marketplace Extension that works with Visual Studio 2013, 2015, 2017 and 2019  is the [Workspace Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyVeselov.WorkspaceManager).

One additional tip: after installing it and adding the toolbar, you might have to restart VS again until it fully works (see [Q & A](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyVeselov.WorkspaceManager&ssr=false#qna)). At least I had to do so in VS 2019 (16.1.3).

Comment: Needed to restart VS 2017 after adding the toolbar for it to be able to save.

Comment: - need to enable it as a toolbar post-installation as per https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndreyVeselov.WorkspaceManager&ssr=false#overview
- needed to restart *twice* (as per Q&A there) in the beginning for its save functionality to work

Comment: I installed the Workspace Manager extension and it saved my screen configuration (i.e. which panels I had open: solution explorer etc.) but it didn't save document groups.

Answer (score 10):

You can save open documents and later reopen them as a group with the [Favorite Documents](http://vlasovstudio.com/favorite-documents/) extension.

Comment: Thanks. This greatly help to save opened tabs. But not with the tab groups.

Comment: @Sergey: Great extension. Still it isn't really usable for me for one reason: I've added all open tabs to a favorite group, but it does not save the group in the order in which the tabs were displayed. For my workflow the tab order is very important. Also the pinned-status is lost, but that would be a minor issue. Would be a winner if the order was maintained!

Comment: This didn't work well for me. It's unable to save groups of tabs. That is all I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Really late to the party but [ContextKeeper](https://ContextKeeper.io) plugin will do the job. Supports VS 2022/2019/2017/2015/2013.

It's an extension to quickly save and restore sets of document tabs and its metadata. The "session", similar to Vim's [:mksession](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:mksession) command, is defined as:

- **last opened/favorites files**
- documents (tabs with code) positions, state and order
- **tabs groups** (including horizontal/vertical orientation)
- remembers line and column for every opened tab
- remembers **breakpoints & bookmarks** for every opened file

It also has a powerful [git integration](https://contextkeeper.io/blog/automatic-snapshot-switching-when-changing-branches-v1/) - **automatically saves** and **restores** context when **switching between branches**.

All contexts are saved to simple JSON files.

Answer (score 3):

If you accidentally came here looking for a VS Code solution, from the same author of [Save All The Tabs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amodio.SaveAlltheTabs) (for Visual Studio) that [MushKov shared in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576359/6225838):

1. [Restore Editors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amodio.restore-editors#overview) extension
2. press <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to access the editors/tab menu

[image: Restore Editors VS Code extension by Eric Amodio]