# How do I save a view of my working files in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Let's say I have two JS, two C# and two HTML files open to work on Feature 1, I'm working on all of these files. Let us call these open files in Visual Studio - "View 1".

Now I have to pause Feature 1 and work instead on a Bug 1, because bug 1 is important and needs an urgent fix. I have a bit of an OCD, so I close "View 1" and open a "View 2", which is the files related to fixing Bug 1, that are different from the files in "View 1". I can deliver the fix quicker if I can "find the correct file to change next" easily.

Once I'm done fixing Bug 1, is there a way I can open up "View 1" without finding all the files in solution explorer and opening them up one after the other manually?

I use GIT and switch branches and all that, but because I'm using the same user profile and repository, my "view" is shared across these branches.

It would help my productivity if I can switch quickly between two views!

Edit: looks like this is a duplicate question. I couldn't find the original because of different wording. [How can I save opened tabs and tab groups in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378005/how-can-i-save-opened-tabs-and-tab-groups-in-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.SaveAlltheTabs), but I don't think there's native support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/index.html#tasks) extension to switch quickly between tasks.